# Rails: calling a model class in a library

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, rspec

I'm trying to verify that a parameter is an instance of a specific class in Rails:

```
def schedule(action, *args)
  if arg.is_a? Aircraft
    ...
  end
end
```

I'm doing this in a library class (the file is in *lib/*) and I get an **uninitialized constant Aircraft** error. Aircraft is a model class, with a corresponding *aircraft.rb* file in *app/models*.

Can I use model classes and instances in a library? How?

---

**Error context:**

The error happens in RSpec tests; the code works in the browser. I tried requiring the model in the *_spec.rb* file, no success at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

You can use model classes in Rails library files and you are doing it in exactly the correct fashion. Rails should autoload the class Aircraft when it is referred to.

So we need a bit more context to figure out why it is failing for you. Is it possible you are loading the lib/ file without the Rails environment?

One way to solve this would be to explicitly require the model file aircraft.rb. However, you will find this approach quickly leads to insanity as it will break the Rails auto-loader in subtle and astonishing ways. Rails is much easier if you work with the Rails class loader, not against it.

*Update*

So if it's in an RSpec test, can we see the code you're using to load the environment in the spec file? It should look something like this:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../spec_helper'
```

and it needs to be at the top of the file. This is assuming both that you have the RSpec Rails plugin installed ([here](http://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec-rails/wikis/home)) and that you have the default spec/spec_helper.rb file from the RSpec plugin. If there is no such file, try running:

```
ruby script/generate rspec
```

Comment: Ah, thank you very much! You pointed me in the right direction: it works perfectly well in the browser. I didn't try it yet because I'm doing TDD: it breaks in RSpec. I'll amend the question.

Answer (score 3):

This will give you access to the Aircraft model:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../app/models/aircraft"
```

[edit]

Daniel brings up a good point about the context. If you're using a rake task make sure you load the environment:

```
task :my_task => :environment do
  # something happens...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Daniel's answer is correct, but consider: why is a library class referring to a model class?  Library code shouldn't know about actual model classes, though it might know about the interface they provide.

Another consideration: why does the `#schedule` method ask for the model's class?  If a new model class, `Spaceship` wanted to work with `#schedule`, then `#schedule` would have to change to work with it.  That's not necessary.

Instead, what's different between the ways that `Aircraft` object and objects of other classes are treated by `#schedule`?  Can you extract that difference into a method of its own?  Then you can move those implementations into each of the model classes, and decide which one is used by polymorphism, not by branching.

For instance, what used to be:

```
def schedule(action, vehicle)
  if vehicle.is_an?(Aircraft)
    possible_days = case action
    when "travel"
      ["Mon", "Wed", "Fri"]
    when "repair"
      ["Sat", "Sun"]
    end
    possible_days.rand
  elsif vehicle.is_a?(Spaceship)
    possible_days = case action
    when "travel"
      ["Sat", "Tue", "Thu"]
    when "repair"
      ["Sun", "Mon"]
    end
    possible_days.rand
  end
end
```

would become:

```
def schedule(action, vehicle)
  vehicle.days_action_can_be_performed(action).rand
end


class Aircraft
  def days_action_can_be_performed(action)
    possible_days = case action
    when "travel"
      ["Mon", "Wed", "Fri"]
    when "repair"
      ["Sat", "Sun"]
    end
    possible_days
  end
end

class Spaceship
  def days_action_can_be_performed(action)
    possible_days = case action
    when "travel"
      ["Sat", "Tue", "Thu"]
    when "repair"
      ["Sun", "Mon"]
    end
    possible_days
  end
end
```

When a new class is added, it just needs to implement `#days_action_can_be_performed`, and it will work with `#schedule`.

Answer (score 0):

Have to tried this one:
`if arg.is_a? ::Aircraft` ?